# Get array parameters multi

Tags: php, arrays, json

I try to take "CompanyName" on all records from "Body" but it doesn't work. I'm asking for help

I tried with $decodedJson->Body->Deeds->Deed->CompanyName

Code ther : https://anotepad.com/notes/kkgkkkaj

Comment: Please include the minimal code necessary to reproduce/understand your problem, directly in your question - in text form, and properly formatted. Do not dump important information on external platforms only. They might disappear from there at any point, leaving the question worthless to any future readers.

Comment: the code is very big and does not allow me to put it here, so I gave a link to an external site

Comment: _Reducing_ this to the minimal example necessary is generally considered your responsibility here. [mre].

Comment: what do you mean by "doesn't work"?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
That looks very irregular json data. U can try something like this.
$a = json_decode($json);
        foreach ($a as $a1){
            foreach ($a1 as $a2){
                if($a2 != ""){
                 foreach ($a2 as $a3){
                     foreach ($a3 as $a4){
                         if($a4 != ""){
                         foreach ($a4 as $a5){
                             foreach ($a5 as $a6){
                                 if(is_object($a6)){
                                    var_dump($a6->CompanyName);
                                 }
                             }
                         }
                         }
                         
                     }
                   
                 }
                }
            }
        }
```